# What are the parameters to install oracle 11g r2 command line?

Tags: oracle, installation

I'm trying to install oracle 11g R2 using a responsefile. I do like this:

```
./runInstaller -responseFile /home/oracle/database/response/db_install.rsp
```

But when I execute the command, it always open my Windows X (I'm using moba Extern). How can I install Oracle 11G R2 in command line?

Note: I want to install software only!

Comment: Check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you forgot to add `-silent`.